# Using Twitter, how can I get a list of all tweets that contain a certain URL?

Tags: php, twitter

I have a blog and for each article I'd like to display all tweets/retweets that contain the URL to that page.  I'd also like to be able to resolve shortened URLs.  Is there any easy way to do this in php5?  Thanks.

Comment: Do you have anything you've tried so far or should I tag this homework?

Comment: I'm not looking for code, I'm looking for some kind of twitter API call that might be able to give me this info.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, call the [search API](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/search) method:

```
http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=http://bit.ly/
```

Comment: When I do this I get inconsistent results.  Try calling the above method and hitting refresh a few times.

Answer (score 0):

Try the Marginize publisher widget: http://marginize.com/publishers

It will find all the tweets about the page and bring them back to the site